# if k>0 and f:R->R satisfies the condition:$\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert$ ≤ k$\lvert x-y\rvert$ for all x,y∈R. Prove that f is continuous at every point c ∈R

Tags: functions, continuity

I try applying the definition of continuity of a function ut I could not see anything useful,and I do not know what else should I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact the condition given can be used to prove a stronger version of continuity, namely uniform continuity. But of course continuity follows, for, taking any $c \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $|f(x) - f(c)| \leq k|x-c|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ by assumption. But taking any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $k|x-c| < \varepsilon$ if $|x-c| < \varepsilon/k$, so taking $\delta := \varepsilon/k$ suffices to prove continuity of $f$.